# Create or use a runtime mesh of an area target at runtime

Tags: mesh, vuforia

in my vuforia engine unity project, I load the vuforia database (dat, xml) at runtime and instantiate an area target with the `ObserverFactory.CreateAreaTarget`. This works great and I can use that area target to observe and track. However, for several reasons (e.g. Navigation, Occlusion) I'd need also to generate or use a pregenerated runtime mesh. The `Add Runtime Mesh` Button is an editor function and adds a corresponding child with a `RuntimeMeshRenderingBehaviour`, where the SouceBehaviour can not be set at runtime.

Is there an option or way to create a mesh for an area target at runtime or use a pregenerated one (how to pregenerate though)?

Thx.

Comment: have you read the documentation here? https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/rendering-in-native/mesh-observer